# pushing svn repository files to the server

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

At present i have am using tortoisesvn. My repository is on a windows server(staging server). when the client connected to the server makes a changes it(repository) gets updated. 
I wanted to update the changes to my LIVE server(linux).
I dont have a subversion setup on my LIVE server. I just wanted to copy files from the windows server Tortoisesvn Repository to a the LIVE server(linux). I tried copying the files manually but i couldn't find my files inside the repository folder. Is there a way to fetch the files and transfer?

Answer (score 1):

This is addressed in the [Subversion FAQ](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#website-auto-update)

Alternatively, check out a working copy on your live server, log into it and run svn update as needed.

Answer (score 0):

This really isn't an ideal solution, but you could write a bash script to which repeatedly calls svn -update every 10 minutes or so.  you'd then just add that to the default runlevel (depending on which distro you're using)